# Can I edit a cell formula without causing the cell to recalculate?

Tags: excel

For example, if I have

```
=INDEX(B1:B100000,MATCH("my_val",A1:A100000,0))
```

in a cell, how can I change that to

```
=INDEX(C1:C100000,MATCH("my_val",A1:A100000,0))
```

without triggering the (slow) Index-Match?

Comment: If you can sort A1:A100000 in ascending order (or if it's already sorted) then you can use LOOKUP here - it will be vastly quicker over such a large range.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking for but consider the use of `INDEX/MATCH` as an alternative that uses less overhead than `VLOOKUP` when looking at large ranges:

```
INDEX(A1:A100000,MATCH("my_val",A1:A100000,0))
```

More info on usage of `INDEX/MATCH` [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/dynamic-searching-using-vlookup-match-and-index-HA001154902.aspx).

Comment: I've edited the question to use index-match, but the issue still stands: I want to change the formula in a cell without triggering a recalculation (which is still slow even with index-match).

Comment: You need to change your calculation in Excel to manual, please follow this tutorial: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/change-when-and-how-formulas-are-recalculated-HP005199227.aspx. In future direct questions of this nature at Super User; Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that in the future. 
I've already set calculations to manual, but Excel still recalculates a formula entered or modified by hand - is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: I don't think that is possible in Excel as it needs to check the validity of the formula you have entered.